# How to store multiline query result in bash variable

Tags: bash, psql

I am executing multiline query and want to store result of query in bash variable.
Following is the query. If I run it without storing its result then it works fine.
But if I want to store its result then it fails.
Can someone tell what I need to correct here to see the execution result of query.

```
result=$(psql postgresql://$USERNAME:$PASSWORD@$HOST:$PORT -c << EOF
CREATE DATABASE $DB_NAME ;
create user $USER with encrypted password '$PASSWORD';
grant all privileges on database $DB_NAME to $USER;

EOF)

echo $result
```

Comment: The actual sql query fails?

Comment: `EOF` needs to be on a line on its own, `)` has to be on the next line.